# In Haskell, when using the XStrict language extension, is if short-circuiting?

Tags: haskell

Standard Haskell is lazily evaluated, so `if myCondition then someValue else doSomeLargeComputation x y z` will avoid evaluating `doSomeLargeComputation x y z` if `myCondition` is true. My question is, if I enable the language extension `XStrict` then will `doSomeLargeComputation x y z` now be evaluated even when `myCondition` is true?

If so, is there a control flow construct other than explicitly marking `doSomeLargeComputation x y z` as lazy that can be used to avoid calculating it (like a short-circuiting if statement in a strict language)?

Comment: `if` is non-strict in any language I know -- this is even more important in impure languages, where you do not want to observe the side effects of both branches. In an (insane, IMO) higher-order language with a strict `if` we could still write `(if cond then (\_-> doX) else (\_-> doY)) ()` to force it to be lazy, but that hack would need to be used to often that it should be the default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the branch not taken is not evaluated.

For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Strict #-}
import Debug.Trace

main :: IO ()
main = print (f (fib 3))

f i =
    if i < 5
        then trace "then" 0
        else trace "else" 1

-- Using fib to avoid inlining or optimization from messing up or test.
fib :: Int -> Int
fib 1 = 1
fib n  = n + fib (n-1)
```

Prints:

```
*Main> main
else
1
```

However, if we lift the branches to let bindings then yes, those are strictly evaluated:

```
f :: Int -> Int
f i =
    let f1 = trace "then" 1 in
    let f2 = trace "else" 2 in
    if i < 5
        then f1
        else f2
```

Yields:

```
% ./LogicChains
then
else
2
```